# How to do an OpenId implementation like in stackoverflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid

I am looking for a sample code/implementation of open id as in stackoverflow.

I need to implement open id in my MVC C# application to allow my users to login with their google, yahoo, AOL,.. accounts.

Please suggest me a good reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) is your friend. Good article on it from [Rick Strahl](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx) about integrating it with MVC.